# How can we migrate cakephp 2.x application to PHP 7.x

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, php-7, php-5.6

How can we migrate cakephp 2.x application to PHP 7.x?

I have a cakePHP based application, which is built in cakePHP 2.9

How can I migrate this to PHP 7.x

Comment: According the the [dcumentation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#requirements) - *CakePHP version 2.8.0 and above support PHP 7*

Comment: But still I am getting an issue Fatal error: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobsite\site\lib\Cake\Utility\String.php on line 26

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981403/cannot-use-object-as-class-name-as-it-is-reserved-cake-2-2-x help for this problem?

Comment: Is there anything not working when simply using a current PHP version with your existing application? Then please share the details by editing your question

Answer (score 0):

Search for references to `String` in your own application code.

For instance with CakePHP 2.10 on PHP 7.2, the following code gives me the same error:

```
App::uses('String', 'Utility');
App::load('String');
```

Not only the framework version you use must be compatible with PHP 7, but your own application code must be too. For this particular case, replace the occurences of the deprecated `String` class by `CakeText`, and it should do the trick.